# Mathquill/ mathjax Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, mathjax, typescript-typings, mathquill

I'm unable to import mathquill/mathjax into ionic2 frame work.

- as mathquill is not available in 'typings'
- in importing mathjax by CDN, it is working for first element of entire appilcation.

thanks in advance.

Comment: DO you want to use it offline?

Comment: Are you able to use your own scripts, stylesheets, and font files?

Comment: i'm coping my css files content into .scss files.

Comment: yes.. i'm thinking about to use it in offline..

Comment: @HanSeoul-Oh do you have any plan for mathquill with typings or compatibility with Ionic2

Comment: If you can use your own files, can you download MathQuill and use those files among your own?